Что нужно написать чтобы импортировать JSON файл?
Хочу импортировать стили взятые из редактора стилей Яндекса, но не могу понять как его правильно написать для импорта?
map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({ theme: "dark", customization: "PASTE_JSON_HERE" }));
Отдельный файл я сделал и вставил туда текст со стилями назвал его ymap.json


JSON - это JavaScript Object Notation. Поэтому можно считать, что json-строка - это просто запись некоторого объекта. Поэтому просто вставляете эту строку вместо PASTE_JSON_HERE:
map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({ theme: "dark", customization: 
{
   "tags": "water",
   "elements": "geometry",
          ... и т.д.
}
}));

